# Multiple GUI one foreach thread in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

I am working on a multi-threaded application in C#/.net
I want each thread to create its own form so it can access it and show its information on its form without any problem
is there any way to do that?
I've tried Application.Run(new MyForm()) but the problem is that this function blocks the execution and my thread can't do its work.

Comment: do form.Show() instead. They are not in separate threads, but they dont block either. Spawning too many forms in different thread doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: why it is not a good idea? I think it is better than updating one gui from all threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. The thread can only do one thing at a time, so if your code runs the UI on that thread will be blocked, and if you want to run a UI you'll have to use some messaging construct (such as a timer) to get your work done.

The proper way is indeed to have one UI thread and have other threads asynchronously post progress messages for being displayed on the UI (using `BeginInvoke` on the form for instance, which is safe to be called from other threads).

Comment: You can also use a `BackgroundWorker`, which has a safe way to marshal status information back to the form.

Comment: Right. I've done this kind of work in .NET 1.1 when there was no BackgroundWorker yet, and I always forget about it. In the meantime I'm doing mostly server development, which saves me from messing with thread-bound window messages...

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Show` method of your form to show it , even if you want to show a form in `Dialog` form you may use `ShowDialog` method, Dialog will be on top of other forms.

Comment: Presumably, each thread will have some sort of information which it will be displaying in real-time in its own window.  So modal forms aren't going to work; they will block.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - you sure about that?  What would happen to the messages carrying objects with data posted to the other forms?  OK, they do not have focus, but they should be still able to process posted messages that do not require focus?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the form from its thread with the Show method, and you can't link between forms from different thread, like MDI parent and child from different threads.
BTW, you can open all forms in the main GUI thread and use invoke to show data from other thread without any problem, and I think this approach is better. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx